# get monthly and weekly average working hours in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has following columns:-  local_id | time_in  | time_out |    date    | employee_id
I have to calculate average working hours(which will be calculated by time_out and time_in) on a monthly basis in PSQL. I have no clue how to do that, was thinking about using date_part function...
here are the table details:

```
 local_id | time_in  | time_out |    date    | employee_id
 ---------+----------+----------+------------+-------------    
        7 | 08:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 2020-02-12 |           2
        6 | 08:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 2020-02-12 |           4
        8 | 09:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 2020-02-12 |           3
       13 | 08:05:00 | 17:00:00 | 2020-02-17 |           3
       12 | 08:00:00 | 18:09:00 | 2020-02-13 |           2
```

Comment: you need to basically use the logic of diff between (out -in) and then use the AVG. function by grouping the data for emp_id's.

See this example:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-avg-function/

Comment: @RajVerma how does this help in calculating the average monthly?And how do you suggest I calculate the time difference?

Comment: Exactly what s-man wrote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b84cf9a0b4cd285dc9e8e27fe2f94af8); [extended example covering two months](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4e265d0fa7e871d34965edcc3aeae96b)

```
SELECT
    employee_id,
    date_trunc('month', the_date) AS month,  -- 1
    AVG(time_out - time_in)                  -- 2, 3
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY employee_id, month                  -- 3
```

1. `date_trunc()` "shortens" the date to a certain date part. In that case, all dates are truncated to the month. This gives the opportunity to group by month. (for your "monthly basis")
2. Calculate the working time by calculating the difference of both times
3. Grouping by `employee_id` and calculated `month`, calculating the average of the time differences.